# How do I get cron to exclude the first day of the month?

Tags: cron

At the moment my script runs every day as follows

```
0 3 * * * wget --timeout=0 http://...
```

Is there some syntax whereby I can exclude the first day of the month i.e. Jan 1, Feb 1, Mar 1... At the moment I shut down manually each month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
0 3 2-31 * * wget --timeout=0 http://...
```